# Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, detailsview

Im trying to retrieve data to a details view on a MVC project.
thiw problem i've got 
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. Help ??

this is the code

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.DataSource = ViewData["item"];
    DetailsView1.DataBind();

}
</script>
```

and this is my function in the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string  ProdNo)
    {

        ProductionOrderItem item = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrder(con, ProdNo);
        ViewData["item"] = item;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The exception seems pretty clear: your `ProductionOrderItem` must implement `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource` to be consumed as a data source.

Comment: i have no dublicated source.

Answer (score 0):

it fixed now
I added a List to the function

```
Public ActionResault Details(string prodNo)
{
ProductionOrderItem item = ProductionOrderReg.GetProductionOrder(con, ProdNo);
        List<ProductionOrderItem> myList = new List<ProductionOrderItem>();
        myList.Add(item);
        ViewData["item"] = myList;
        return View();
}
```